# Why is postgres not pushing down join

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, sharding

We have the following test setup for sharding/paritioning:

Master node:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_id INTEGER, 
  sample INTEGER
) PARTITION BY HASH(customer_id);

CREATE TABLE orders (
  customer_id INTEGER,
  product_id INTEGER,
  sample INTEGER
) PARTITION BY HASH(customer_id);

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw;

CREATE SERVER IF NOT EXISTS shard_1 
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
  OPTIONS (dbname 'shard_1', host 'shard_1', port '5432');
CREATE SERVER IF NOT EXISTS shard_2 
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
  OPTIONS (dbname 'shard_2', host 'shard_2', port '5432');

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE customer_1 PARTITION OF customer
  FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 2, REMAINDER 0)
  SERVER shard_1;
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE customer_2 PARTITION OF customer
  FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 2, REMAINDER 1)
  SERVER shard_2;

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE orders_1 PARTITION OF orders
  FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 2, REMAINDER 0)
  SERVER shard_1;
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE orders_2 PARTITION OF orders
  FOR VALUES WITH (MODULUS 2, REMAINDER 1)
  SERVER shard_2;

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR admin SERVER shard_1
  OPTIONS (user 'admin', password 'admin');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR admin SERVER shard_2
  OPTIONS (user 'admin', password 'admin');

INSERT INTO customer VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (2, 5),
  (10, 3),
  (14, 2);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES
  (1, 2, 1),
  (2, 13, 4),
  (12, 3, 2),
  (18, 1, 3),
  (14, 5, 5);
```

Shard nodes:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer_<1/2> (customer_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, sample INTEGER UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE orders_<1/2> (customer_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, product_id INTEGER UNIQUE, sample INTEGER UNIQUE);
```

We would like to have joins executed on the shards in order to ease the load on the master database. But it does not always push down the joins when `enable_partitionwise_join` is set to `on`:

E.g. why does the following query not push down the join:

```
explain (analyze, verbose, costs off) select * from customer join orders using (customer_id) where customer.customer_id=1;
                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop (actual time=2.524..2.530 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: customer.customer_id, customer.sample, orders.product_id, orders.sample
   ->  Foreign Scan on public.customer_1 customer (actual time=1.289..1.290 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: customer.customer_id, customer.sample
         Remote SQL: SELECT customer_id, sample FROM public.customer_1 WHERE ((customer_id = 1))
   ->  Materialize (actual time=1.229..1.232 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: orders.product_id, orders.sample, orders.customer_id
         ->  Foreign Scan on public.orders_1 orders (actual time=1.184..1.185 rows=1 loops=1)
               Output: orders.product_id, orders.sample, orders.customer_id
               Remote SQL: SELECT customer_id, product_id, sample FROM public.orders_1 WHERE ((customer_id = 1))
 Planning Time: 0.283 ms
 Execution Time: 3.974 ms
(12 rows)
```

While a query like this does?:

```
explain (analyze, verbose, costs off) select * from customer join orders using (customer_id) where customer.sample=2;
                                                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Append (actual time=1.681..3.324 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Foreign Scan (actual time=1.679..1.681 rows=1 loops=1)
         Output: customer_1.customer_id, customer_1.sample, orders_1.product_id, orders_1.sample
         Relations: (public.customer_1) INNER JOIN (public.orders_1)
         Remote SQL: SELECT r4.customer_id, r4.sample, r6.product_id, r6.sample FROM (public.customer_1 r4 INNER JOIN public.orders_1 r6 ON (((r4.customer_id = r6.customer_id)) AND ((r4.sample = 2))))
   ->  Foreign Scan (actual time=1.636..1.636 rows=0 loops=1)
         Output: customer_2.customer_id, customer_2.sample, orders_2.product_id, orders_2.sample
         Relations: (public.customer_2) INNER JOIN (public.orders_2)
         Remote SQL: SELECT r5.customer_id, r5.sample, r7.product_id, r7.sample FROM (public.customer_2 r5 INNER JOIN public.orders_2 r7 ON (((r5.customer_id = r7.customer_id)) AND ((r5.sample = 2))))
 Planning Time: 0.411 ms
 Execution Time: 5.365 ms
(11 rows)
```

I mean even when the first query would not have the where clause the query could be pushed down to each shard because `customer_id` is the sharding key and they both have the same partition bounds (which is referred to as the only criteria by many sources). Why isn't this done?

Or also this one:

```
explain (analyze, verbose, costs off) select count(*) from customer where customer_id = 1;
                                         QUERY PLAN                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate (actual time=1.260..1.262 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(*)
   ->  Foreign Scan on public.customer_1 customer (actual time=1.249..1.251 rows=1 loops=1)
         Remote SQL: SELECT NULL FROM public.customer_1 WHERE ((customer_id = 1))
 Planning Time: 0.352 ms
 Execution Time: 2.257 ms
(6 rows)
```

Wouldn't it be clear that the query can be pushed down when postgres knows that it will hit only one shard? (`enable_partitionwise_aggregate` is also `on`).

**Edit**:

We are using PostgreSQL 13

Comment: Please declare your version of Postgres (always).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I added it to the post, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Does really no one have an answer?